# Multivalued Facet in broadleaf

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Is it possible to have a product with multiple search facet values assigned at once? If so how? I thought this would be handled by the "String (Multi)" Facet Field Type:

```
<dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

but it doesn't seem to pick up more than one value per product.

Here is an example of what I would like to set up:

Search facet: Demographic
Values: Men, Women, Children

I have added a record on BLC_FIELD with a property name pointing to an ArrayList of Strings. And I have also indexed them by modifying the SolrIndexService buildDocument. The field is something like this for one document:
demographic_ss: [Men, Children]

Product A associated to both the Men and Children values.

When Its reaching the category page to display the facet, The facet fields being pulled for demographic is null
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize I18nSolrSearchServiceExtensionHandler.addPropertyValues(). Because _ss field requires string array value.

```
if (field.getFacetFieldType() == FieldType.STRINGS) {
     propertyValue = StringUtils.toStringArray(propertyValue);
}
```